# Auto tab doesn't work with text in-between?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The title says it, auto-tab is not working with text in-between two text boxes.

Basically, it won't tab between two text boxes when there's a span in-between the two text boxes.

Here's what doesn't work:

HTML

```
<input class="fill-out" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
<span class="text">x</span>
<input class="fill-out" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
<span class="text">x</span>
<input class="fill-out" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".fill-out").keyup(function () {
    debugger
        if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
          $(this).next('.fill-out').focus();
        }
  });
```

As I said above it does not work, however, if I remove the two spans everything works perfectly fine.

JavaScript stays the same I only remove the two spans:

HTML

```
<input class="fill-out" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
<input class="fill-out" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
<input class="fill-out" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".fill-out").keyup(function () {
    debugger
        if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
          $(this).next('.fill-out').focus();
        }
  });
```

Can anyone explain why, or if there's another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery, [next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) will find the immediate following element.  Using the selector means that it will only return that immediate following element **if** the element matches your selector.

You should use [nextAll()](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) instead, which will find all those items that fit the selector... and then use [first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) to use the first one.

```js
$(".fill-out").keyup(function () {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    $(this).nextAll('.fill-out').first().focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="fill-out" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
<span class="text">x</span>
<input class="fill-out" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
<span class="text">x</span>
<input class="fill-out" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
```

Alternatively, you could also use the CSS pseudo-class [`:first`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/:first-child) instead of the `first()`...

```
$(this).nextAll('.fill-out:first').focus();
```

---

Really, this should be a new question, but based on the OP's comment...

> Is there a way for it to deselect the text box if there's none to go-to anymore?

To "deselect" the cursor after the last item has been entered, you could do the following, where you store the "next" item and if it's not there you `blur()` the current one.

```js
$(".fill-out").keyup(function () {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    var $next = $(this).nextAll('.fill-out').first().focus();
    if ($next.length == 0) {
      $(this).blur();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="fill-out" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
<span class="text">x</span>
<input class="fill-out" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
<span class="text">x</span>
<input class="fill-out" type="text" maxlength="1"/>
```

You don't need to create the `var $next` but I think it's easier to read than the following which would just take the `.length` directly...

```
if ($(this).nextAll('.fill-out').first().focus().length == 0) {
  $(this).blur();
}
```

Comment: Not a problem @William - good luck with the rest of your project

Comment: Is there a way for it to deselect the text box if there's none to go-to anymore?

Comment: Sure, it should really be a separate question, but it's a quick one I guess. See the edit